# Find MAX value in a range with several Columns and Rows and return the value contained in row 1 and Column C

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

[image]

I get the maximum value with the `MAX function` (A2) and I would like in the cell written **FROM (B4)** comes the corresponding value from row 1 that found this maximum value and in the cell written **TO (B6)** comes the highest corresponding value from Column C.

I tried to use the `VLOOKUP` function but was unsuccessful because it is not a common vertical return.

Link to Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uScFepHOAlscLzbmpGIlvPOKbnAfpiPvwZj7GX3HE9Y/edit#gid=1640450499&range=A1:B6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below formula to get column value.

```
=INDEX(A1:AO1,,ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(IF(TodosOsRanges=MAX(TodosOsRanges),COLUMN(TodosOsRanges)))))
```

And following formula to get row value.

```
=INDEX(C1:C101,ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(IF(TodosOsRanges=MAX(TodosOsRanges),ROW(TodosOsRanges)))))
```

See your sheet. I have edited to your provided sheet also.

Comment: I followed the creation of the formula through the spreadsheet, thank you very much for being available to help me!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

alternative:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(IF(TodosOsRanges=MAX(TodosOsRanges),COLUMN(TodosOsRanges)-4)))
```

[image: 0]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(IF(TodosOsRanges=MAX(TodosOsRanges),ROW(TodosOsRanges)-1)))
```

---

`-4` for an offset of 4 columns = D column is start

`-1` for an offset of 1 row = 2nd row is the start